# Centering and integrating image gallery

Tags: html, css, image

HTML/CSS newbie question for you.

I've been stuck on this for awhile. I'm looking to center my image gallery AND also make the padding between the images tighter. I'm thinking I need a container but, I've just been screwing it all up when I try.    Any help would be great!

```
    <div id="container" align="center">
<div class="img">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="#" alt="PIcture1" width="210" height="180">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">BLAH</div>
</div>


<div class="img">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="Images/9700_1915630577543_1314909545_n.jpg" alt="oldman" width="210" height="180">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">BLAH</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="#" alt="Picture3" width="210" height="180">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">BLAH</div>
</div>

<div class="img">
    <a href="#">
    <img src="#" alt="Picture4" width="210" height="180">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">BLAH</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container{
}

div.img
  {
  margin:5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border:none;
  height:auto;
  width:auto;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  }
div.img img
  {
  display:inline;
  margin:5px;
  border:none;
  }
div.img a:hover img
  {
  border:none;
  }
div.desc
  {
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:normal;
  width:120px;
  margin:5px;
  }
```

Comment: The doc type you're using could be important to providing a good answer.  Can you provide the head section of your html?

Comment: the html `align` attribute is deprecated. You'll want to use css to center your element by giving it an explicit width and using `margin: 0 auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you want to centre your gallery.

There's a few things that you need to bear in mind. In order to centralise some HTML you need to have a set width of the centralising element.

Here's some code for you to work with:

Create a "centre" class in CSS as follows:

```
div.centre{
    margin:0px auto;
    width:800px;
}
```

Then add it to your container as follows:

```
<div id="container" class="centre">
```

The secret to centralisation is in the **margin:0px auto;**, this is convention of modern web development to centralise content.

[Have a look at this code](http://jsfiddle.net/W5UH2/1/)

p.s. don't use **align="center"** it is depreciated in later versions of HTML. Better to not get into the habit of using it and stick to using CSS classes to centralising things for you.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to close your question by accepting the answer. (clicking on the tick) :)

Answer (score 0):

You should not use align. It is a deprecated property. To center something with a container you need to specify a fixed width and add margin auto.

Ex:

```
#container {
width:970px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

You can remove the padding on div.img